# Vector spaces... why is one a vector space but the other is not?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am reading this text:

[image]

and this:

[image]

What is the difference here? Why is the set of 2nd degree polynomials or less a vector space but the set of 2nd degree polynomials not? What is the diff?

I don't understand why this sentence is needed:

> The zero vector in this space is the zero polynomial given by $0(x) = 0x^2 + 0x + 0$, for all x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all they are different as sets. The zero polynomial is in the set of polynomials of degree $\le 2$, but not in the set of degree $=2$. (A polynomial of degree 2 must have the form $ax^2+bx+c$ where $a\ne 0$.)

Once you understand their difference as sets, you know why the latter is not a vector space because the zero polynomial is not in it, so it has no zero element!

Answer (score 0):

Vector spaces must be closed under addition. The sum of two polynomials of degree $n$ can be of any degree $\le n$, but the set of polynomials of degree two doesn’t include any polynomials with degree less than two. In particular, it doesn’t include $0$.